# asp.net toolkit calendar

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

i'm using this control for date picker.
   i want that when user click on button the calender will pop up next to the button
   and when the user pick date the date will save in hidden field or somthing like that.

the probelm is that the control need target control and he can't get hidden field
   i don't want to show the date the user pick. only to save this date somehow

thanks!!!!

Comment: don't say it "won't work" without try first! I always do the code before post it :P so i know it always work, eheheh

Comment: made a screencast 4 u ... so, know, dont say it does not work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not hidding the Textbox (target control ID)

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="hide" ...

.hide { display: none; }
```

Works fantastic! Maybe you don't know how to implement it :)

for that:

> [Here is a **screen cast** of it](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showFlash.aspx?swf=2009-08-19_1203_StackOverflow_CalendarHideTextbox.swf&w=998&h=672).

Comment: I've just tried like <asp:TextBox Style="display:none;" and it works.

Comment: NEVER, EVER add styles directly ... use CSS, that is why they are available to you, it is not a good pratice and when you ned up with plenty of code it will be a nightmare. Remember: Always create Reusable Code!